# UICollectionView isn't working when extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars is set to true

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have UIViewController which extends UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

}
```

UICollectionviewDelegate and DataSource methods aren't called, so UICollectionview appears to be empty. Even if I call reload data, DataSource methods still arent called.

When I delete last line, everything works fine except there is space below viewController.

Answer (score 0):

**edgesForExtendedLayout**

> Basically, with this property you set which sides of your view can be
>   extended to cover the whole screen. Imagine that you push a
>   UIViewController into a UINavigationController, when the view of that
>   view controller is laid out, it will start where the navigation bar
>   ends, but this property will set which sides of the view (top, left,
>   bottom, right) can be extended to fill the whole screen.

You need to set one of these two

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

OR

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

may be it will help you.

Comment: I already tried this, but didn't help.
only extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false removes the space.